# URL rewriting using .htaccess on static url

Tags: html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem on turning my static URL into dynamic URL. I'm planning to use .htaccess to solve this problem but it doesn't seem to work on my part.

<sub>I am also using an API to fetch the movie title and year.</sub>

how do I change my static URL
[https://www.website.com/detail.html]
into dynamic url:
[https://www.website.com/{page_title}](https://stackoverflow.com)
like this: [https://streamify-io.netlify.app/spirited-away-2001](https://stackoverflow.com)

here's my code but it doesn't seem to work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d{4})$ detail.html?movie=$1&year=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Does your host support Apache/.htaccess? The regex you are using clearly does not match the example URL you’ve posted. Your example URL ends with `-2001`, but your regex is expecting `/2001`. You've also not stated clearly exactly the URL pattern you are expecting. You described it as `/{page_title}`, but your rule would seem to be expecting `/{page_title}/{4_digit_year}`?